# Foreign key on different tables is it possible?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Assume that I have an entity called "Vehicle" and the attribute is "Vehicle_ID" and I set it as a Primary Key.

I have another 2 entities called "Travel Form" & "Reservation Form". Can I put the vehicle_id into these 2 entities as a foreign key ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? (Seriously, welcome to S.O. The guide for new users at http://stackoverflow.com/tour specifically says "Don't ask questions you haven't tried to find an answer for.")

Comment: Yes you can. It's the whole point of foreign keys.

Comment: This is an assignment , i cannot try anything before i ask , we have to draw an ERD with a summary

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  definitely do this.By using `Foreign key` we can make relations with tables etc

See [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/37628) for more reference